# Why do I get an error with rmarkdown when I want to load the 'forecast' package?

Tags: r, time-series, reporting, r-markdown

Sorry, I am new to rmarkdown.
I always get an error when I try to Knit the document. When I run this section normally in R I do not have any problems. It seems like the problem specifically has to do with the forecast package.. Does anyone have an idea?
Code:

````
```{r, include=F}
install.packages("sandwich")
library(sandwich)
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)
```
````

Error message:

```
Error in library(forecast) : there is no package called 'forecast'
```

Many thanks

Comment: Install the packages outside the document. So run `install.packages(...)` in the console and delete those lines inside the rmd document.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for my purpose!